# OpenGL 4.0 on ubuntu 13.04 using an intel graphics card

Tags: 13.04, drivers, intel, opengl

I have a new laptop with an Iris Pro 5200 integrated graphics card, everywhere I look it says that this card supports OpenGL 4.0.

The reason why I want 4.0 (or 3.3+ to be more specific) is that I'm doing an assignment for uni where I've received an OpenGL 3.3 compliant GLSL shader to improve, but I can not compile/run it as I only have OpenGL 3.0.

Calling `printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));` after an OpenGL context has been created prints: `"3.0 Mesa 9.1.4".`

For the people with Nvidia graphics cards I see that the solution is to install proprietary graphics drivers, but as far as I know Intel only has open source graphics drivers. Is this correct?

I'm a novice at best when it comes to linux and especially graphics programming, so please, bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenGL 4.0 is not yet supported with the Intel Linux Graphics driver (as reported by your glGetString() call). There is no proprietary driver, so you are stuck with this until they release a driver with support for this.

Support for OpenGL 4.0 likely means it is implemented for Windows.